# Как применить middleware "auth" ко всем роутам?

Tags: laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.6, laravel5.4

Использую группу:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::post...
    Route::post...
    ...
}
```

Хотелось бы убрать эту группу из роутов, но все же делать проверку для всех их. Как это сделать? Теоретически я знаю, что нужно просто в Кернеле в массив $middleware добавить нужный мидлваре. Но почему-то у меня так не получилось:

```
protected $middleware = [
    ...
    ...
    \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
];
```

Вылетает ошибка: This page isn’t working, хотя логи при этом пустые.

Как это правильно реализовать?

Comment: чем вас не устраивает группа?

Answer (score 0):

в Kernel есть свойство middlewareGroups, там и применяйте

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,

            //customMiddleware
            \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: так не работает. Если я не авторизован, то у меня идут бесконечные запросы на /login

Comment: @YuriyLyubimiy тогда создайте новую группу роутов в RouteServiceProvider.php и задайте middlewar там